# Send() using TCP is not sending the whole array

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, send

I am trying to send a `char` array to a server and I am not able to send the whole thing. I discovered that I am not receiving  that it is sending only the first four packets.

This is the data I want to send in one go.

```
char msg1[]={0xff,0xfd,0x03,0xff,0xfb,0x18,0xff,0xfb,0x1f,0xff,0xfb,0x20,0xff,0xfb,0x21,0xff,0xfb,0x22,0xff,0xfb,0x27,0xff,0xfd,0x05,0xff,0xfb,0x23};
```

This is the function I am using to check whether all the bytes have been send or not. and if not. send the rest.

```
int send_all(int s,char *buf,int *len)
{
    int total=0; //total bytes sent
    int byteslft= *len; //bytes left to be sent
    int n; //value returned by send() 

    while(total<*len)
    {
        n=send(s,(buf+total),byteslft,0);
        if(n== -1)
            break;

        total +=n; //total bytes sent will be in total
        byteslft -=n; //total bytes left to be sent is stored here
    }

    *len= total;
    return (n==-1)?-1:0;
}
```

And this how I am trying to send it

```
len=sizeof (*(arr+i)) ;
    if((numbytes=send_all(sockfd,(*(arr+i)),&len))==-1)
    {
        perror("send");
        continue;
    }
```

I have done the connect(),socket(), etc. steps before this just to be clear.

And this is how I've initialized the array of the pointers to the `msg` array.

```
char *arr[]={msg1,msg2,msg3,msg4....};
```

When I debug my program, I see that it is only sending

```
ff fd 03 ff //message stops sending here
```

And that's why I'm not getting the required response from the server.

Comment: I have shown how `array` is initialized.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `arr` and how you initialize it.

Comment: By the way, since you have a variable called `byteslft` (pointless abbreviation, btw) you should use that in the while loop. Notice how `while(bytesleft > 0)` reads somewhat better than `while(total < *len)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `*(arr + i)` is not an actual array, but a *pointer* to an array. This means that the `sizeof` operation will return the size of the *pointer* (which is 32 bits, i.e. four bytes on a 32-bit operating system) and not what it points to.

You can only use `sizeof` to get the size of an array if you have the actual array, not on pointers.

Comment: I need to get the size of the array `msg1` in order to send the data.

I didn't realize that it would return the pointer size. 

Is there any way I can get the `sizeof` msg from the pointer?

Comment: @ad3 No, there is no way. You might want to keep a second array with the sizes.